# Android - Place two ImageView's side by side with margin in between

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout, android-tablelayout

This is what I want: [image]

Left image 45%, middle 10% and right 45% and the height of all of them should stay proportional to width

This is what I tried:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView13">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageLeft"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.45"
            android:src="@drawable/placeholder_white" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/margin"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:src="@drawable/placeholder_white" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageRight"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.45"
            android:src="@drawable/placeholder_white" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

But the result is nonsense

How can I do that? Do I need to use a Table Layout?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `android:layout_width="0dp"` for every child into LinearLayout and replace `android:layout_height="0dp"` for LinearLayout to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` and set concrete `android:layout_heigh` for every child. For example:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageLeft"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.45"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@color/black" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/margin"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:src="@color/blue" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageRight"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.45"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@color/red" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT: attached a picture**
[image]

**EDIT: attached screenshot with image 48dp**
[image]

Comment: Nope, the images are staying the same size instead of filling the 45%/10%/45%

Comment: Can you show all your layout file. Maybe problems in another part of the code?

Comment: It supposed to be images not colors, the images are staying the same size

Comment: No, it does not affect. With images it works correctly also

Comment: Please show me screenshot ^^ but use images with like 50dp x 50dp like I do. But also with normal images the left and right ones are jumping below the mid image. Omg this is more annoying than dealing with CSS in web

Comment: Look! I highlighted with color so that the borders were visible.

Comment: I need the IMAGES to be 45%/10%/45% dude. And their heights should adjust based on ratio to width. I said all that already in the question and provided example as image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181993/discussion-between-p-alexey-and-donkinged).

Comment: Ok when I replace the colors with true images as it supped to then it works, thanks!